# Cross Platform Platform

Tags: asp.net-mvc, multilingual, multiplatform

General question: 
If I wanted to develop a web site, say ASP.NET MVC (the only web framework I am familiar with), is it generic enough so I can use it to have later apps for iOS, Android, obviously Windows Phone?
I mean I will need to connect somehow to SQL server that is the backend of the ASP.NET MVC web site etc. What are technical difficulties & considerations I need to take into account so that app is generic enough.
Note that I am planning it to be multilingual and will use ASP.NET resources to support that.

Or should I learn completely different framework to have it generic over multiple platforms?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

ASP.Net is generic enough. You can expose REST endpoints (although WebAPI is probably better to do that, but you can run that alongside, and consume from, MVC), create full user interfaces, etc.

However, if you are planning a write-once, run-anywhere application to avoid having to develop native device apps (e.g. Android and IOS), make sure to take the time to read [this excellent (but long) article](http://sealedabstract.com/rants/why-mobile-web-apps-are-slow/).

Answer (score 0):

The MVC framework can definitely be used for mobile devices (when you say apps, I am assuming you mean websites that function as apps), and MVC 4 introduced significantly more support for mobile development, including things like templates (http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes#_Toc303253809).

MVC is a move to a less heavy handed framework than, for example, Webforms, and it should give you the flexibility to develop for any device. However, it does also open you up to coding yourself into some problems if you approach it in the wrong way, so make sure you are familiar with the framework before trying to develop some super next-gen responsive web app.

Answer (score 0):

You can expose your ASP.NET MVC controllers to other platforms, like web services or Web API, so the client, IOS, Android or anything else can call your services.